# how to pass two parameters to call a stored procedure through c# mvc function

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I can do it easily when I need to pass a single parameter as follows:

```
 public ProjectsModel GetProjectListBySearch(int projectId)
    {
        try
        {
            using (_context = new Exo_ADBEntities())
            {
                var getdetailprojectlist = _context.Database.SqlQuery<ProjectsModel>("exec dbo.[GetProjectListByID] @ProjectID", new SqlParameter("@ProjectID", projectId)).FirstOrDefault();
                return getdetailprojectlist;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

This works nicely but when I try to do the same kind of thing but passing two parameters I find syntax error called invalid parameter Please help me to do this.Code when using two parameters are as follows

```
 public List<ProjectsModel> GetProjectDetailsBySectorAndSubSector(int sectorid,int subsectorid)
    {
        try
        {
            using (_context = new Exo_ADBEntities())
            {
                var projectbysectorandsubsector = _context.Database.SqlQuery<ProjectsModel>("exec dbo.[GetProjectDetailsBySectorAndSubSector] @sectorId,@subSectorId", new SqlParameter("@sectorId, @subSectorId", sectorid, subsectorid)).ToList();
                return projectbysectorandsubsector;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If so, please, accept it as answer to make it usefulfor other people.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to pass several parameters as a single object.

If you [look at the signature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696545%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) of `Database.SqlQuery` you'll see this:

```
public DbRawSqlQuery<TElement> SqlQuery<TElement>(
string sql,
params Object[] parameters
)
```

This is too basic, but, when you see `params` in a C# function it means "any optional number of parameters". What this means is that you can pass as many parameters as needed. So, in your case, it's simply like this:

```
_context.Database.SqlQuery<ProjectsModel>(
  "exec dbo.[GetProjectDetailsBySectorAndSubSector] @sectorId,@subSectorId", 
  new SqlParameter("@sectorId", sectorid),
  new SqlParameter("@subSectorId", subsectorid)
).ToList()
```

Note that when you find `params Object[]`, you can also pass an array instead of several params, i.e.

```
_context.Database.SqlQuery<ProjectsModel>(
  "exec dbo.[GetProjectDetailsBySectorAndSubSector] @sectorId,@subSectorId", 
  new Object[] { new SqlParameter("@sectorId", sectorid),
                 new SqlParameter("@subSectorId", subsectorid)}
).ToList()
```

Depending on how your code looks like this can be more convenient.

Comment: Thanks for this answer!  I had missed the commas between the parameters

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options available to you.

Either pass the view model back to the controler, this is my personal preference.

Or setup a new route in global.asax that takes two parameters.

Or you can manually do the form post and pass the two parameters using jQuery inside the view

Comment: yes I am passing data from view to controller using jquery and the function is also able to retrieve those two parameters but I am not being able those parameters

Comment: "but I am not being able those parameters", you're not able to do what with the parameters?

Comment: Ah wait a minute, you need to create two SqlParameters one for each variable passed, not one SqlParameter for both

Comment: yes that is my question how to write for two SqlParameters ,I tried this but its not the way I know :          var projectbysectorandsubsector = _context.Database.SqlQuery<ProjectsModel>("exec dbo.[GetProjectDetailsBySectorAndSubSector] @sectorId,@subSectorId", new SqlParameter("@sectorId", sectorid ),new SqlParameter("@subSectorId",subsectorid).ToList();

Comment: That's the way I do it as well, what's the error you get when you do that?

Comment: catch returns this error:Procedure or function 'GetProjectDetailsBySectorAndSubSector' expects parameter '@subSectorId', which was not supplied.

Comment: When creating the SqlParameter drop the @ sign before the parameter name, that might solve you're problem