# Pass multiple parameters to call stored procedure with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, stored-procedures

I want to call a stored procedure in my Linq code. When I use only one parameter, it works fine, but when I want to use multiple parameters, it shows an error.

Here is what I have done - this work fine:

```
 SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@Value1", val);
 var abc = db.tablename.SqlQuery("SP_Name @Value1", param1).ToList();
```

Now I want to add second parameter

```
SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter("@Value2", val2);
var abc = db.tablename.SqlQuery("SP_Name @Value1,@Value2", param1, param2 ).ToList();
```

it returns an error:

> An error occurred while reading from the store provider's data reader. See the inner exception for details.

Comment: share the error too?

Comment: "An error occurred while reading from the store provider's data reader. See the inner exception for details." ... WELL - show us your inner exception details...

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23976618/how-to-pass-two-parameters-to-call-a-stored-procedure-through-c-sharp-mvc-functi

Comment: @Chandru thanks for response. error was due to mismatch data type in SP and parameters.

Comment: var param1 = new SqlParameter();
param1.ParameterName = "@Value1";
param1.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int;
param1.SqlValue = val;

Comment: then you have to provide data type for each sql parameter.

Comment: @Chandru thanks solved.

Answer (score 3):

Hope this sample code helps you!!

```
var param1 = new SqlParameter(); 
param1.ParameterName = "@Value1"; 
param1.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int; 
param1.SqlValue = val1;

var param2 = new SqlParameter(); 
param2.ParameterName = "@Value2"; 
param2.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar; 
param2.SqlValue = val2;

var result = db.tablename.SqlQuery("SP_Name @Value1,@Value2", param1, param2 ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I used the Store procedure with 2 parameters you can use as per your need.

```
adxGYMDataContext db = new adxGYMDataContext();
var mysp = db.sp_memb_info_get_del(int.Parse(txt_id_memb.Text), true).Select(x=>x).ToList();

foreach (var item in mysp)
{
cmb_duration_memb.Text = item.memb_dur.ToString();
txt_tel_memb.Text = item.memb_tel.ToString();
}
```